# query session on parse server always got invalid session token message

Tags: function, session, parse-platform, cloud, parse-server

I have some code in the cloud to query the sessions on parse-server. The code works fine on the parse.com but it always got the `"invalid session token"` message when I call the same code on the parse-server. Here is the code:

```js
Parse.Cloud.define("getSessionCount", function(request, response) {
    if (request.user == null) {
        reportError("deleteAllOtherSessions", "userCheck", 0);
        response.error("invalid user");
        return
    }

    //the user that sends the request
    //var currentUser = request.user;
    //console.log(currentUser);
    //send from client 
    var currentUserInstallationId = request.params.installationId;
    var userSessionQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Session);  //session query can only return the session related to the user
    //all sessions of this user
    //userSessionQuery.equalTo('user', currentUser);
    //except the session for this installation -> to not log the request performing user out
    userSessionQuery.notEqualTo('installationId', currentUserInstallationId);

    userSessionQuery.find({
        success: function(results) {
            response.success(results.length);
        }, 
        error: function(err) {
            //TODO: Handle error
            response.error(err);
        }
    });
});
```

Anyone has the same issue or know how to solve this??

Comment: What version of parse-server are you running?

Comment: I am using the latest version of Parse server. However, I already figured out the solution. When using the querying for such internal data types, e.g. Sesssion, User, Installation, you must use the master key.